# .swift viewcontroller missing (!)

Tags: xcode, viewcontroller

In my project navigator, a .swift file that connects to a viewcontroller has an "!" next to it and says that it's "missing".

When I click on the file, it shows the code for that viewcontroller, and my app works, but the title bar in the mainstoryboard for that viewcontroller doesn't match the file name.

I'm not sure what the problem is or how to fix it. Thanks! [image: How the file appears in the navigator]

Comment: That's a source code control (git?) issue.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this?